# Build a question and answer for solve doubts about how to search music and / or identify it

Tags: discussion, new-users

**Background**

Before posting my [question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/techno-house-theme-where-interpreter-naming-roman-emperors-in-the-lyrics), first, I had to write all details that I vaguely can remember about that theme song that I heard on radio, TV, or any other media.

Usually, when I'm trying to identify some song:

- I try remember part of the lyrics and/or the music style, genre, artist etc.
- Search in Google, YouTube, etc.
- Posting a very-vague question on Yahoo!
- Using software for music identification (like Shazam) ***if** the song may appear again or **if** I have recorded the sample*.
- If maybe I heard the song on radio, I try to send a message to radio station, but they usually don't answer those *questions*...

If after those steps, I was unable for find the song. I'm more orientated to post my question in a music site.

I must recognize that not all users follow these steps before make questions in any of the Stack Exchange sites. The provided details produces *low quality questions* that may be closed and *without the help of the community of the site*, it would be difficult that those users go back again.

Checking in another Stack Exchange sites like [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), there exist a very comprehensive question and answer about a very common question requested by the users:

> How do I root my Android device?

So, my question is:

**May exist a question (with his accepted answer) about how to get better results about music identification?**

In that way, that question would be used as a guidance for help new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guideline question and answer is already **[in this link](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721)**.

I invite you to improve those guidelines for build a definitive, clear and step-by-step tutorial about how create questions and answers for music identification questions.

Answer (score 4):

I would say yes.  People do it now, and sometimes there are votes to close them.  However, if you've done that much due diligence before asking the question, then you're definitely not asking the question because you're lazy.

Answer (score 2):

You described a good backgound job to do before asking a question. I would also add that a an identification question must have an interest for the next person that could be in the same situation.

In a poor post like

> - https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-name-of-this-song.

I can't see how another user asking himself the same question will google and end in this question.

In good posts like

> - [What Metal song is used in this trailer for an upcoming animated movie?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/what-metal-song-is-used-in-this-trailer-for-an-upcoming-animated-movie)
> - [Video clip of a song in a beach, big guy with pink sunglasses](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/video-clip-of-a-song-in-a-beach-big-guy-with-pink-glasses)
> - [Instrumental waltz music used in old "Popeye" cartoon (unknown music from 30's or earlier)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/instrumental-used-in-old-popeye-cartoon-unknown-music-from-30s-or-earlier)

There a enough details and keywords to be found with google, so another user can find it.

**Try to add keywords that the next person in your situation would have in mind.** Is it a song from a commercial, from a movie, the opening theme of a tv show...?