# What should I do to improve my identification question?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, etiquette, faq-proposed

When I ask an identification question (tagged `identify-this-*`), I receive downvotes and comments indicating that my question is not up to the standard.

Why does this happen? What can I do to improve my ID question so as to avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **What should I do to improve my identification question?**

Here are some tips to help you improve your question:

- Search on Google using terms like:

  - Part of the lyrics. Here you can specify the language *(if you know it)* of the song you're looking for.
  - Name of the artist(s).
  - Music cover image, describing it or if you have the image, add it too.
  - Music genre (rock, pop, reggae, jazz...).
  - When did you hear the song ***or*** if you know it, the year of production.
  - Where did you hear the song *(radio station, commercial, etc)* or where you did watch the video *(YouTube, etc.)*.
  - *If you have heard a similar theme* you can add the similarities with the music you're looking for.
  - Any other details that you can remember about the song.
- If Google didn't return any results, use any of the following websites or other sites dedicated to searching for music also *using the terms mentioned above*:

  - [Find Music By Lyrics](http://findmusicbylyrics.com/)
  - [Lyricsmania](http://www.lyricsmania.com/)
  - [Lyrically](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Lyrics_Wiki)
  - [Metrolyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/)
  - [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/) *yes, you can search there, some video descriptions contain information that can lead you to a possible answer.*

When searching, **search beyond page one**, trust me, maybe your answer is on page 2 or even page 3 *(this is specially true in Youtube, so many videos...)* :)

- *If you have a recorded sample*, use music identification software (like [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/) or [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/)) or keep those programs at hand for the next time the song may appear again.
- *If you heard the song on a radio station or any other commercial media*, try to contact them via email, Twitter, et cétera.

With the results that you have gotten so far and adding info like:

- *Discarded similar themes*: let's say that I found 3 samples on Youtube that sound similar, but they're not the song I'm looking for.
- *Covers*: let's say that I found the song, but it's interpreted by a male singer, but you remember that the original singer was actually a woman.

You have already improved your question massively. good luck and we hope to be able to help you with accurate answers!

If you have indeed found the song, congratulations!, we invite you to answer your own question so other users will recognize your results and will enjoy listening to music that they might not otherwise have listened to.

Comment: "Find Music by Lyrics"--bah!  "Uses Google's search technology" but does a piss-poor job compared to just doing the search on Google.

Comment: @WGroleau can you clarify, please? I'm not familiar with the terms you're using.

Comment: The advice above to use "Find Music by Lyrics".  The site sucks.  It changes a phrase search to individual words, sends it to Google and then puts Google's results in a really bad format.  But Shazam or SoundHound might work.

Comment: @WGroleau thanks for clarify. I listed Shazam and SoundHound. I invite you to [edit] this answer and give more tools you consider useful for the community.

Comment: The only others I know of are only useful for matching whole CDs to MusicBrainz or GraceNotes.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't downvote you. But I think some people may have downvote because the way you asked the question looked like you were asking us to do the whole job for you. You should first say what you have already tried so we won't do it again:

- Have you tried to find them on google, or youtube?
- Have you tried to contact the artist?
- Have you checked the booklet in the disc box (or inner sleeve)?
- Have you tried to listen and write what you understood, I'm sure there is some parts you can understand a little. If there is some missing parts you can publish the understood parts, and we will help you to fill the rest.

Comment: I didn't buy cd I've been listening song online also tried google but couldn't find. Sometimes artists don't pay attention such queries of fan's or listeners and I couldn't get most part of song and so I've missed such things in first place them may I can't expect answer her. Also English isn't my first language.

Comment: @Swapnil, you can say all that in the question, so people will now you have made some effort.

Comment: @Swapnil Please do not worry about English not being your first language. Just do your best to write a thorough and detailed question and someone will come along behind you and straighten out any issues with the spelling, grammar, etc. - that's what edits are for.

Comment: @Bebs I'll be careful of this things.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I don't mean for writing but listening and understand. I.e watching movies with subtitles But thank you sometimes I do mistake you mentioned.