# Attaching the melody?

Tags: support, asking-questions

If my question or answer includes a short piece of a melody, what's the best way to include it?

An example would be a question to identify a song I remember from a long time ago, and I only remember the melody, some of which I'd determined the exact relative pitches.

- Just writing notes, like D(1) C(1) D(1) F(2) G(1) ... where the number in brackets indicates the length? (Easy to copy, paste, edit etc.)
- A picture of a score sheet? (Gives pretty much the same information).
- A recording of humming / playing on a piano...?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good questions and I'm glad someone asked it.

First of all, you should add the more details you can around the song itself. [Here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question) is a list of what details can be helpful. I think this is more important than the melody itself.

Then, to include the melody, the most people can read the question, the better are the chances you will find an answer. Consider that some people can't read chords or score sheets so it would be better to include a recording or to write it to a sequencer like [onlinesequencer.net](https://onlinesequencer.net/).