# "identify-this-song" requisites?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The tag [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) states

> Be sure to include enough information (lyric snippets, a good quality sound clip, etc.)

I have two songs I am trying to find, to identify the band. However all I have is the melody in my head from one song, and the "plot" of the video clip from another. Obviously the melody won't be useful, but would the video clip description be enough?

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350). As for the melody in your head, you might be interested in [Attaching the melody?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436)

Answer (score 4):

and welcome.

First, you can read Andrew's suggestion (as a comment). Then you need to ask two different questions because each case is different.

For the first one, "melody in my head", specify the genre, featuring "special" instruments, approximate date when it was trending, the language, the country, which media. Maybe you van remember a few lyrics...? Any detail matter and [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question) you will find a list of relevant details. Then you can eventually add a recording of you humming the song, or play it in an instrument, or an online sequencer.

> Obviously the melody won't be useful

I disagree with that. Any detail matter and could eventually ring a bell to someone. There is no reason to hide a detail if remembered.

For the second one, "plot of the video", try to remember which media, country etc... **please try to remember something about the actual music**. ID questions with no music details are often closed.