# What is the best SE site to ask for Spanish Catholic song identification?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I want to find the names and original composer or artist of these songs I heard in my childhood from 2000-2006, and I'd also like to find lyrics for them, as well.

I can probably record the melody as I remember them using something like Audio Clyp or YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Your can ask your questions here as long as they fill the requirements or our identification question rules.

You can read this other meta question: [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question)

It basically says that you need to give as much detail as possible.

It is also not clear if you want to identify several questions or only one, but if it is several, I suggest you separate each identification in one question and use the tag [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song).

Unless all the songs come from the same album, ask them all at once then use [identify-this-album](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-album).

If they all come from the same artist, or band, ask them all at once and use [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist) or [identify-this-band](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-band).

Comment: They are basically five songs. I don't know if they are by the same artist, band, album, etc, but three of them are church songs, and two of them are Spanish infantile songs.
If I am asking for five songs to be identified, should I ask five separate questions on SE, or make one question with a link leading to the recording with the five melodies played one after the other?

Comment: It would be better to ask five separate questions, as each answer will be different and one can answer to one, but not the others.