Should we revisit allowing identity questions?
So, we experimented with a ban on identify questions for the past few years. We've had ample time to evaluate it. Was it a good move? Should we keep it? Or should we revisit allowing them?

I think it was a good call and one of the reasons I started participating here more actively.
Other sites on the network, most notably Sci-fi & Fantasy, is drowning in these kind of - to me personally - very uninteresting questions. When the majority of questions are very uninteresting ones to me, I naturally lose interest in the site as whole. Sci-fi & Fantasy is rapidly dying because of it IMO - floods of uninteresting questions isn't necessarily good for a site.
Also this kind of uninteresting identification stuff is one of the few areas where AI ought to actually be quite useful, so they are hopefully doomed and we'll bed rid of them in the near future.

Fine on the rest of your answer but SF&F is "rapidly dying"? After 12 years, and with 151K users? Where are you getting that idea from?

@ChrisSunami From them guys posting stats with the sede database output showing user decline network-wide.

I'd be happy to review those numbers if you post a link. But unless the decline started over a decade ago, it isn't related to ID questions.

No. This ignores most of the discussion around these types of questions.
First off, they started off as off topic as seen here:

"Identify this song / genre / artist" - on topic?

Then there was a push to get them on topic and that was supposed to be the trial:

Why identify-this-* tag hasn't been banned?
Identification questions in general. What is allowed, and what is not?

Then there many posts about the problems we had with those questions. Most encapsulated in this meta post:

The [identify*]-question question: Time for a trial separation?

Then finally where we are now they were fully moved off-topic (not a trial off-topic period):

Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps


The tl;dr of all the discussions was the quality of the questions were the problem. We were getting a lot of low effort questions that the OP would fire and forget along with people voting up answers that the OP said were incorrect. With no guide for quality, most questions in that vein being ignored, and encouraging shot in the dark answers it hurt the site more than anything else.
Just liking them to discover new music and just wanting more questions ignores why every discussion about them has made a good number of users say no to having these questions. No one is saying you can't like these questions. No one is saying discovering new music is bad. We're saying as an SE site, the questions we allow affect our quality and we need the ability to up their quality if we are going to allow them.
Unless there is a community supported proposal to help deal with the quality, there is nothing to reconsider. Every proposal in that vein got ignored so I really don't see a path forward. At this point any discussion that doesn't at least mention quality is missing a huge chunk of the input from the past discussions.

Since statistics were brought up, it's worth looking at the numbers, post ID ban.
https://data.stackexchange.com/musicfans/query/1863303/musicfansengagementbyyear#graph
As we can see, usage had stabilized around the low 200s starting in 2018, and maintained those numbers through 2020.
It dropped sharply after ID questions were banned, and has continued to drop. This place is now a ghost town, with less than 1/4 the usage we had before.
The number of unique users took a similar hit.
While I agree that bringing up the quality of questions and the amount of engagement is key, it's clear to me at this point that banning ID questions as a route to that is a failed experiment. It didn't stimulate new, higher-quality questions, it just eliminated the bread-and-butter questions that were keeping us alive. The current data indicates a site headed towards extinction.

The sharpest drop is from 2020. The ban as we're talking about started in 2022. The raw data shows absolutely no info about quality which again is the focus of why they were made off-topic again. If all you care about is the number of questions we get and not about the scope or quality, then there's really not much to talk about as just getting more questions does not make the SE better.

Also there's more than one part of engagement. Answers, votes, comments are also included in typical engagement in similar queries.

Here's a popular query about engagement: https://data.stackexchange.com/musicfans/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph. There is a slight downtrend on the 2022 period, but it's not crazy because the overall numbers are pretty low. There's actually currently a spike in new users and votes which is pretty crazy.

"It didn't stimulate new, higher-quality questions, it just eliminated the bread-and-butter questions that were keeping us alive" I believe most of us already know that new non-ID quality questions are not increasing either. I guess the real question is if that's what this community wants to be, MusicIdentification.SE.

I'd also say they were not "bread and butter". They were slop that pushed out everything. This is clearly demonstrated in the stat section of the post where it's clear ID questions were not being engaged with by the site. https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-identify-question-question-time-for-a-trial-separation. I very much feel like a broken record harping on the quality, but it's literally the core part of the reason so much time has been put into even having this discussion.

Speaking as the all-time top user--both in the identity and no-identity eras--I think it was a bad decision from the start. Just as I suspected, it did not lead to a board renaissance, and a sudden influx of new, good, non-identity questions, it just reduced most of our traffic and engagement.
It didn't bring our community together. If anything, it divided people and drove them away.
I think we should unban them. People who don't like them can just ignore them. Personally, I always enjoyed them. I discovered a lot of new music that way.

Allowing them drove people away and left us with nothing but random id questions from drive by users. Liking or not liking them was not the issue. It was quality in pretty much every discussion.  Ignoring them made the site a ridiculously low quality site that pretty much prevented us from graduating.

@Dom They've been off-topic a good long while now, and the only change I perceive in the site is a ton less use and engagement. Maybe I'm wrong, but I'm not seeing this as a great improvement.

Shoving low quality questions on the site won't fix engagement.  Again the engagement went down when we allowed the id questions as shown in https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-identify-question-question-time-for-a-trial-separation. I'd argue the engagement peaked with the closing of id questions as it brought both sides of the id question to the meta for a bit, but the engagement was not brought by just having id questions. One more time I will say see the last paragraph of my answer.

Can you at least address why you're ignoring anything mentioning quality as a concern. This is one of many metas that bring it up that points out how the community felt about these low quality questions: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/no-effort-no-research-no-use-to-future-visitors
